# Is it possible to hide link address on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have set up a chart with a lot of links and it really bugs me when it shows where the link goes in the bottom left hand side of the browser whenever you hover on a link, like so:

[image]

Is it possible to remove this? any method will do as long as I can hide/remove it (HTML, CSS, JS etc..)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Itay because it's just an internal works organisational chart and it annoys me when I can see it pop up in the corner whenever you hover on a link to a colleague

Answer (score 6):

The status bar highlighting happens only when you use an `<a>` element with a set `href`.

If you use pure JavaScript to open your link, and don't assign a `href` attribute, nothing will turn up in the status bar.
I don't know how much control you have over the chart html, but if it renders `<a>` tags there's not much you can do.

You could try running javascript after the chart is renderred to attach `onclick` event handlers manually to all `<a>` tags and set `href = '#'`.

Comment: Is that the only possible way then?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem that led me to this thread. I figured I'd post my solution here rather than start a new thread about it.

I have a WordPress site with complex menus, and those menus had subheadings which the theme rendered as `<a>` links with empty href values. The site manager didn't want the bottom corner to display as a link if those were hovered over, since they didn't work has a link anyway.

```
<a href="#" class=" no_link" style="cursor: default;" onclick="Javascript: return false;">
```

I tried removing the "#" under `href` but it still showed the site's root url on hover.

Since the anchor tag's class list already included `no_link` as a class, I simply added the following jQuery to the global JavaScript file:

```
$("a.no_link").removeAttr("href");
```

Note that the intention was to simply remove a link's address on hover if it wasn't supposed to be a functional link anyway.

Answer (score -4):

Refer this link here :

```
 http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Miscellaneous/Q_21278295.html
```

However , if the chart is not under your control, then this may not nbe the way

As suggested in the link :

```
<a href="www.google.com" onMouseOver="window.status=' '; return true;">Pink Floyd</a>
```

You can also use jQuery to bind the mouseover event on these anchor links without editing individual `<a>`