# Hide url display in bottom left on mouseover?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge

I would like to hide the url display that appears in the browser when you hover over a link. I've read the other articles posted on this subject, but as I've tested the options, my functionality "breaks." I have some links that open in the same page, some open a new tab, and other prompt lightbox, pinterest and twitter widgets, and none of the solutions thus far seem to be a "one-size fits all" fix.

I've found a solution (I think), but development is not my forte, and I have no idea how to implement this. Is this something that someone can give me a step by step on how to make this change?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.isstatusbarenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.674-prerelease

Comment: _"...I would like to hide the url display that appears in the browser when you hover over a link..."_ why ? I can't think of a legit reason to do this.

Comment: Is this in your own application or are you looking to modify a browser? 
Please show a [mre]

Comment: I would like to modify what people see when they view my website.

Comment: I apologize, but I don't really have an example since I'm so unfamiliar with how to even begin.

Comment: The URL display is a security feature so an end-user can see the true URL before they click on it.  If it could be suppressed / hidden / modified then phishing sites would use it to disguise the true destination URL(s).

Comment: @Richard Critten - that makes sense. We sell products that many online discount sites also sell. However, we are brick and mortar, and offer free design services. Many people take advantage of this and spend hours upon hours in our showroom, then take the information and search for better pricing online. We have de-branded our products as much as possible, but if you hover over our product images, you can see exactly what the product is, as the images were saved with specific vendor information for ease of maintenance. We are trying to change that, but this is an interim fix.

Comment: You should consider every byte of data that your server sends to a browser client to be accessible: including URLs. The accessibility of some of this data depends on how savvy the user is, but **none of it is truly private/hidden**. Trying to override accessibility and/or security features in browsers is never going to produce a positive outcome for your users.

Comment: One idea: you can convert raw image data to an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), which would create a random name and even prevent the user from sharing the link with others (as the URL would be ephemeral). You can try it in your console right now to see an example of text blob data (although you'd be using image data instead): `console.log(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['hello world'])));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand your concern regarding your business.

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.isstatusbarenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.674-prerelease) you have shared is for WebView2.

Microsoft WebView2 is a developer control for embedding web content in applications. It allows developers to leverage the best of what the Microsoft Edge Chromium platform can offer and build seamless experiences for their users that incorporate web-based content.

It cannot help you hide the URLs on hover for the images on your site while visiting it through different browsers.

As informed by the other community member, it is a security feature in the browsers so users could know which site they are going to visit if they click the link. It is not recommended to modify it to hide it for security reasons.

further, you don't know that the customers visit your site using which browser. Every browser works differently and it is not possible to remove/ hide or disable that information from the browser side.

There are some code examples I found that use some JS code to achieve your requirement. You need to modify your site code. If you are not a developer then it could be difficult for you and you may break your site. So it is recommended to take help from your site developers.

Below are the helpful links.

1. [How To Hide url display in bottom left on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335367/how-to-hide-url-display-in-bottom-left-on-mouseover)
2. [How to hide link information at the bottom left/right of the browser on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410748/how-to-hide-link-information-at-the-bottom-left-right-of-the-browser-on-hover)
3. [how can url be hidden in hyperlink when mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851372/how-can-url-be-hidden-in-hyperlink-when-mouse-hover)
4. [Is it possible to hide link address on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452543/is-it-possible-to-hide-link-address-on-hover)

The best thing would be to remove the unwanted information from the image links.